# My webform is in lightbox when I submit on the webform it should redirect to the page where webform is displaying

Tags: jquery, webforms

My webform is in lightbox when I submit on the webform it should redirect to the page where webform is displaying. Currently it redirects to the webform page.

Answer (score 0):

### Redirect to an overlay does not work that way

The problem is when a form is displayed in a lightbox, it appears in an overlay. That overlay element is called from a separate URL. Submitting the form is going to work relative to the URL called by the overlay, not on the page where the overlay happens to be displaying.